# A way to set custom start and end time for Google Timeline Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Couldn't find answer in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline).

By default, Google Timeline "shrinks" the chart area, so that first bar touches the left edge, and last bar touches the right:

```
 |XXXXX-----YYYY---------|        
 |----ZZZ---YYYY----AAAAA|        
Apr     May     Jun     Jul
```

I want to override this behaviour and manually set start and end time for chart (override the scale), like this:

```
 |------------XXXXX-----YYYY----------------|        
 |---------------ZZZ----YYYY-----AAAAA------|        
 Jan   Feb   Mar  Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug
```

In my example, I want to show the chart from January till August.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

listed in the [Release Notes from October 2, 2015](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#october-2-2015)

use options `hAxis.minValue` & `hAxis.maxValue`

```
    hAxis: {
      minValue: new Date(2017, 0, 1),
      maxValue: new Date(2017, 7, 1)
    }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ '1', 'A', new Date(2017, 1, 1), new Date(2017, 1, 10) ],
      [ '2', 'B', new Date(2017, 3, 1),  new Date(2017, 3, 10) ],
      [ '3', 'C', new Date(2017, 5, 1), new Date(2017, 5, 10) ],
    ]);

    function drawChart() {
      chart.draw(dataTable, {
        hAxis: {
          minValue: new Date(2017, 0, 1),
          maxValue: new Date(2017, 7, 1)
        }
      });
    }

    $(window).resize(drawChart);
    drawChart();
  },
  packages: ['timeline']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!